# GitLab CI rules to fetch or clone

Tags: gitlab-ci

I want to have my pipeline to use "git fetch" most of the time, except when the branch name matches "release-[0-9]+.*$": I want a "git clone" then.  This applies only to merge requests.

I basically had the workflow example from the GitLab doc (only `if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG` was added):

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
```

To get the correct strategy, I made the following changes:

```
variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: "clone"

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME !~ /^release-[0-9]+.*$/
      variables:
        GIT_STRATEGY: "fetch"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
```

It works as before, except it fetches.  But it fetches instead of cloning when the branch name is "release-9.9.9" for example.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `But it fails to clone` What do you mean it fails? Can you provide the log output from the job?

Comment: I want clone when the branch is for a release.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to have my pipeline to use "git fetch" most of the time, except when the branch name matches "release-[0-9]+.*$": I want a "git clone" then. This applies only to merge requests.

I think you may want to change a bit in your code. It should look like:

```
# Default all pipelines use "git fetch"
variables:
  GIT_STRATEGY: "fetch"

workflow:
  rules:
    # "git clone" if your branch name matches the regex AND your branch is merging into "master/main" branch on a merge request
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^release-[0-9]+.*$/
      variables:
        GIT_STRATEGY: "clone"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    # I think this '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH' rule should be changed to "when: never" 
    # to avoid duplicate while having Merge request pipeline (from the first rule) 
    # and Branch pipeline (this rule) created once pushed
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
      when: never
```

Also, I think we should remove this rule below because it seems to be redundant here

```
- if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS'
  when: never
```